# How do you iterate through every file/directory recursively in standard C++?

Tags: c++, filesystems

How do you iterate through every file/directory recursively in standard C++?

Comment: You may want to examine boost.filesystem http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Comment: Not standard C++: http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.DirectoryIterator.html

Comment: This should soon be in the standard via the [Filesystem TS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs), with the [recursive_directory_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/recursive_directory_iterator)

Comment: If use of  a standard C library doesn't get in the way of calling a C++ program as 'standard', [nftw()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/nftw).  Here's a practical [example](https://github.com/six-k/dtreetrawl/blob/f7c1d320225ee754b96fef28bb0774a2c34b91b8/dtreetrawl.c#L473)

Comment: Somebody, who knows what they're doing, should take an hour to update this.

Comment: The trouble with all the range-based "beauty-shot" answers is that it's unsuitable for serious production use, for the lack of per-iteration error recovery. It's all or nothing. By the time you catch an exception, the loop is gone. OTOH, if you want to protect all the fragile parts individually, horror ensues: the loop has to be dissected, and the result won't resemble anything remotely pretty -- and the `++` op (`increment()`) could _still_ fail irrecoverably... That (and related crashes deemed too costly to debug) was when I abandoned the std rec. dir-iterator altogether, as "still a toy".

Answer (score 104, accepted):

In standard C++, technically there is no way to do this since standard C++ has no conception of directories. If you want to expand your net a little bit, you might like to look at using [Boost.FileSystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm). This has been accepted for inclusion in TR2, so this gives you the best chance of keeping your implementation as close as possible to the standard.

An example, taken straight from the website:

```
bool find_file( const path & dir_path,         // in this directory,
                const std::string & file_name, // search for this name,
                path & path_found )            // placing path here if found
{
  if ( !exists( dir_path ) ) return false;
  directory_iterator end_itr; // default construction yields past-the-end
  for ( directory_iterator itr( dir_path );
        itr != end_itr;
        ++itr )
  {
    if ( is_directory(itr->status()) )
    {
      if ( find_file( itr->path(), file_name, path_found ) ) return true;
    }
    else if ( itr->leaf() == file_name ) // see below
    {
      path_found = itr->path();
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: C++ has no concept of files?  What about std::fstream?  Or fopen?

Comment: Update with regard to latest boost version:  In case anyone stumbles across this answer, the latest boost includes a convenience class boost::recursive_directory_iterator so writing the above loop with explicit recursive call is no longer necessary.  Link:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#Class-recursive_directory_iterator

Comment: You should probably replace itr->leaf() with itr->path().leaf() ('leaf' : is not a member of 'boost::filesystem::directory_entry')

Comment: VC++11 comes with much the same functionality in the <filesystem> header under the std::tr2::sys namespace.

Comment: I haven't written actual C++ code in ages. Someone who is more up to date should edit this to be more modern

Comment: [`std::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) is finally included in the ISO standard as of **C++17**.

Comment: No need for boost.  The OP specifically asked for standard c++.

Comment: This used to be a good answer, but now that <filesystem> is standard, it's better to simply use is (see other answers for an example).

Comment: Instead of the deprecated `leaf()`, use `path().filename()`.
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/filesystem/doc/deprecated.html

Answer (score 126):

From C++17 onward, the [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) header, and range-`for`, you can simply do this:

```
#include <filesystem>

using recursive_directory_iterator = std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator;
...
for (const auto& dirEntry : recursive_directory_iterator(myPath))
     std::cout << dirEntry << std::endl;
```

As of C++17, `std::filesystem` is part of the standard library and can be found in the `<filesystem>` header (no longer "experimental").

Comment: Avoid usage of `using`, use `namespace` instead.

Comment: And why is that? Better more specific than bringing in things you don't use.

Comment: Review my edit please, I've also added missing namespace std.

Comment: [<filesystem>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) is no longer a TS. It's part of C++17. You should probably update this answer accordingly.

Comment: Note for mac users, this requires OSX 10.15 (Catalina) at a minimum.

Comment: Some notes: **1)** `dirEntry` is `std::filesystem::directory_entry`, we can e.g. `dirEntry.path().string()`. **2)** std::filesystem's `recursive_directory_iterator` or `directory_iterator` is iterator, so we can e.g. `++it`, `*it`, etc. **3)** std::filesystem's [`begin` and `end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/begin) enable these directory iterators to be used with range-based for loops, such as this answer. **4)** The iteration order of directory iterators is unspecified.

Answer (score 52):

If using the Win32 API you can use the **FindFirstFile** and **FindNextFile** functions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200(VS.85).aspx

For recursive traversal of directories you must inspect each **WIN32_FIND_DATA.dwFileAttributes** to check if the **FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY** bit is set. If the bit is set then you can recursively call the function with that directory. Alternatively you can use a stack for providing the same effect of a recursive call but avoiding stack overflow for very long path trees.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool ListFiles(wstring path, wstring mask, vector<wstring>& files) {
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    wstring spec;
    stack<wstring> directories;

    directories.push(path);
    files.clear();

    while (!directories.empty()) {
        path = directories.top();
        spec = path + L"\\" + mask;
        directories.pop();

        hFind = FindFirstFile(spec.c_str(), &ffd);
        if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)  {
            return false;
        } 

        do {
            if (wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L".") != 0 && 
                wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L"..") != 0) {
                if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                    directories.push(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                }
                else {
                    files.push_back(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                }
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
            FindClose(hFind);
            return false;
        }

        FindClose(hFind);
        hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<wstring> files;

    if (ListFiles(L"F:\\cvsrepos", L"*", files)) {
        for (vector<wstring>::iterator it = files.begin(); 
             it != files.end(); 
             ++it) {
            wcout << it->c_str() << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how long did it take you to write that?  I think it would take less time to glue C++ to python and do it in one line.

Comment: This is a nice, non-recursive solution (which is sometimes handy!).

Comment: Btw, if anyone wants to edit the program slightly to accept a command-line parameter argv[1] for the path instead of a hardcoded one ("F:\\cvsrepos"), the signature for main(int, char) would change to wmain(int, wchar_t) like this:  int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])

Comment: Thanks, but this function does not work with Cyrilic. Is there any way to make it work with Cyrilic characters like - б, в, г etc ?

Answer (score 35):

You can make it even simpler with the new [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) range based `for` and [Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_%28C++_libraries%29):

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;    
struct recursive_directory_range
{
    typedef recursive_directory_iterator iterator;
    recursive_directory_range(path p) : p_(p) {}

    iterator begin() { return recursive_directory_iterator(p_); }
    iterator end() { return recursive_directory_iterator(); }

    path p_;
};

for (auto it : recursive_directory_range(dir_path))
{
    std::cout << it << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: No need for boost.  The OP specifically asked for standard c++.

Comment: @CraigB It's a good answer for those that are stuck with the compiler they have and can't use C++17.

Answer (score 28):

A fast solution is using C's [Dirent.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirent.h) library.

Working code fragment from Wikipedia:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int listdir(const char *path) {
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dp;

    dp = opendir(path);
    if (dp == NULL) {
        perror("opendir: Path does not exist or could not be read.");
        return -1;
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dp)))
        puts(entry->d_name);

    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This routine isn't recursive.

Comment: @TimCooper, of course it doesn't, dirent is posix specific.

Comment: Actually it *does* work on VC++ if you get a port of dirent.h for visual C++ by Tony Ronkko. It's FOSS.
I just tried this and it works.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator`. But beware, this includes symbolic (soft) links. If you want to avoid them you can use `is_symlink`. Example usage:

```
size_t directory_size(const std::filesystem::path& directory)
{
    size_t size{ 0 };
    for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(directory))
    {
        if (entry.is_regular_file() && !entry.is_symlink())
        {
            size += entry.file_size();
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Last but not least, actually better than previous answers.

Comment: This is the correct answer if you are using C++17

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the above mentioned boost::filesystem you may want to examine [wxWidgets::wxDir](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxdir.html) and [Qt::QDir](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.5/qdir.html).

Both wxWidgets and Qt are open source, cross platform C++ frameworks.

`wxDir` provides a flexible way to traverse files recursively using `Traverse()` or a simpler `GetAllFiles()` function. As well you can implement the traversal with `GetFirst()` and `GetNext()` functions (I assume that Traverse() and GetAllFiles() are wrappers that eventually use GetFirst() and GetNext() functions).

`QDir` provides access to directory structures and their contents. There are several ways to traverse directories with QDir. You can iterate over the directory contents (including sub-directories) with QDirIterator that was instantiated with QDirIterator::Subdirectories flag. Another way is to use QDir's GetEntryList() function and implement a recursive traversal.

Here is sample code (taken from [here](http://www.digitalfanatics.org/projects/qt_tutorial/chapter08.html) # Example 8-5) that shows how to iterate over all sub directories.

```
#include <qapplication.h>
#include <qdir.h>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    QApplication a( argc, argv );
    QDir currentDir = QDir::current();

    currentDir.setFilter( QDir::Dirs );
    QStringList entries = currentDir.entryList();
    for( QStringList::ConstIterator entry=entries.begin(); entry!=entries.end(); ++entry) 
    {
         std::cout << *entry << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doxygen uses QT as its OS compatibility layer.  The core tools doesn't use a GUI at all just the directory stuff (and others compenents).

Answer (score 9):

Boost::filesystem provides recursive_directory_iterator, which is quite convenient for this task:

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

recursive_directory_iterator end;
for (recursive_directory_iterator it("./"); it != end; ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;                                    
}
```

Comment: What is "it" please? Isn't there a syntax error? And how do you feed the "end"? (=how   know we parsed all the dir?)

Comment: @yO_ you're right there was a typo, default constructor for recursive_directory_iterator will construct an "invalid" iterator, when you finished iterating over dir it will turn "it" will become invalid and will be equal to "end"

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`ftw(3)` or `nftw(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftw) to walk a filesystem hierarchy in C or C++ on [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) systems.

Comment: https://github.com/six-k/dtreetrawl/blob/f7c1d320225ee754b96fef28bb0774a2c34b91b8/dtreetrawl.c#L473 has an example of this. The code does a few more stuff, but it acts a good tutorial for `nftw()` usage.

Answer (score 7):

We are in 2019. We have [filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) standard library in `C++`. The `Filesystem library` provides facilities for performing operations on file systems and their components, such as paths, regular files, and directories.

There is an important note on [this link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) if you are considering portability issues. It says:

> The filesystem library facilities may be unavailable if a hierarchical file system is not accessible to the implementation, or if it does not provide the necessary capabilities. Some features may not be available if they are not supported by the underlying file system (e.g. the FAT filesystem lacks symbolic links and forbids multiple hardlinks). In those cases, errors must be reported.

The filesystem library was originally developed as `boost.filesystem`, was published as the technical specification ISO/IEC TS 18822:2015, and finally merged to ISO C++ as of C++17. The boost implementation is currently available on more compilers and platforms than the C++17 library.

**@adi-shavit has answered this question when it was part of std::experimental and he has updated this answer in 2017. I want to give more details about the library and show more detailed example.**

[std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) is an `LegacyInputIterator` that iterates over the directory_entry elements of a directory, and, recursively, over the entries of all subdirectories. The iteration order is unspecified, except that each directory entry is visited only once.

If you don't want to recursively iterate over the entries of subdirectories, then [directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) should be used.

Both iterators returns an object of [directory_entry](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry). `directory_entry` has various useful member functions like `is_regular_file`, `is_directory`, `is_socket`, `is_symlink` etc. The `path()` member function returns an object of [std::filesystem::path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) and it can be used to get `file extension`, `filename`, `root name`.

Consider the example below. I have been using `Ubuntu` and compiled it over the terminal using

**g++ example.cpp --std=c++17 -lstdc++fs -Wall**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

void listFiles(std::string path)
{
    for (auto& dirEntry: std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(path)) {
        if (!dirEntry.is_regular_file()) {
            std::cout << "Directory: " << dirEntry.path() << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        std::filesystem::path file = dirEntry.path();
        std::cout << "Filename: " << file.filename() << " extension: " << file.extension() << std::endl;

    }
}

int main()
{
    listFiles("./");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You would probably be best with either boost or c++14's experimental filesystem stuff. **IF** you are parsing an internal directory (ie. used for your program to store data after the program was closed), then make an index file that has an index of the file contents. By the way, you probably would need to use boost in the future, so if you don't have it installed, install it! Second of all, you could use a conditional compilation, e.g.:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS //define WINDOWS in your code to compile for windows
#endif
```

The code for each case is taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/67336/7077165

```
#ifdef POSIX //unix, linux, etc.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int listdir(const char *path) {
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dp;

    dp = opendir(path);
    if (dp == NULL) {
        perror("opendir: Path does not exist or could not be read.");
        return -1;
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dp)))
        puts(entry->d_name);

    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}
#endif
#ifdef WINDOWS
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool ListFiles(wstring path, wstring mask, vector<wstring>& files) {
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    wstring spec;
    stack<wstring> directories;

    directories.push(path);
    files.clear();

    while (!directories.empty()) {
        path = directories.top();
        spec = path + L"\\" + mask;
        directories.pop();

        hFind = FindFirstFile(spec.c_str(), &ffd);
        if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)  {
            return false;
        } 

        do {
            if (wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L".") != 0 && 
                wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L"..") != 0) {
                if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                    directories.push(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                }
                else {
                    files.push_back(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                }
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
            FindClose(hFind);
            return false;
        }

        FindClose(hFind);
        hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    return true;
}
#endif
//so on and so forth.
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't. The C++ standard has no concept of directories. It is up to the implementation to turn a string into a file handle. The contents of that string and what it maps to is OS dependent. Keep in mind that C++ can be used to write that OS, so it gets used at a level where asking how to iterate through a directory is not yet defined (because you are writing the directory management code).

Look at your OS API documentation for how to do this. If you need to be portable, you will have to have a bunch of [#ifdef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Conditional_compilation)s for various OSes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call OS-specific functions for filesystem traversal, like `open()` and `readdir()`. The C standard does not specify any filesystem-related functions.

Comment: What about C++? Are there any such functions in iostream?

Comment: Only for files. There aren't any kind of "show me all the files in a directory" functions.

Comment: @1800: Directories are files.

Answer (score 3):

On C++17 you can by this way :

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    for (const auto &entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(".")) {
        if (entry.path().extension() == ".png") {
            std::cout << entry.path().string() << std::endl;
            
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't. Standard C++ doesn't expose to concept of a directory. Specifically it doesn't give any way to list all the files in a directory.

A horrible hack would be to use system() calls and to parse the results. The most reasonable solution would be to use some kind of cross-platform library such as [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29) or even [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX).

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, you can use the FindFirstFile together with FindNextFile API. You can use FindFileData.dwFileAttributes to check if a given path is a file or a directory. If it's a directory, you can recursively repeat the algorithm.

Here, I have put together some code that lists all the files on a Windows machine.

http://dreams-soft.com/projects/traverse-directory

Answer (score 0):

File tree walk `ftw` is a recursive way to wall the whole directory tree in the path. More details are [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ftw).

NOTE : You can also use `fts` that can skip hidden files like `.` or `..` or `.bashrc`

```
#include <ftw.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

 
int list(const char *name, const struct stat *status, int type)
{
     if (type == FTW_NS)
     {
         return 0;
     }

     if (type == FTW_F)
     {
         printf("0%3o\t%s\n", status->st_mode&0777, name);
     }

     if (type == FTW_D && strcmp(".", name) != 0)
     {
         printf("0%3o\t%s/\n", status->st_mode&0777, name);
     }
     return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     if(argc == 1)
     {
         ftw(".", list, 1);
     }
     else
     {
         ftw(argv[1], list, 1);
     }

     return 0;
}
```

output looks like following:

```
0755    ./Shivaji/
0644    ./Shivaji/20200516_204454.png
0644    ./Shivaji/20200527_160408.png
0644    ./Shivaji/20200527_160352.png
0644    ./Shivaji/20200520_174754.png
0644    ./Shivaji/20200520_180103.png
0755    ./Saif/
0644    ./Saif/Snapchat-1751229005.jpg
0644    ./Saif/Snapchat-1356123194.jpg
0644    ./Saif/Snapchat-613911286.jpg
0644    ./Saif/Snapchat-107742096.jpg
0755    ./Milind/
0644    ./Milind/IMG_1828.JPG
0644    ./Milind/IMG_1839.JPG
0644    ./Milind/IMG_1825.JPG
0644    ./Milind/IMG_1831.JPG
0644    ./Milind/IMG_1840.JPG
```

Let us say if you want to match a filename (example: searching for all the `*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png` files.) for a specific needs, use `fnmatch`.

```
 #include <ftw.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fnmatch.h>

 static const char *filters[] = {
     "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png"
 };

 int list(const char *name, const struct stat *status, int type)
 {
     if (type == FTW_NS)
     {
         return 0;
     }

     if (type == FTW_F)
     {
         int i;
         for (i = 0; i < sizeof(filters) / sizeof(filters[0]); i++) {
             /* if the filename matches the filter, */
             if (fnmatch(filters[i], name, FNM_CASEFOLD) == 0) {
                 printf("0%3o\t%s\n", status->st_mode&0777, name);
                 break;
             }
         }
     }

     if (type == FTW_D && strcmp(".", name) != 0)
     {
         //printf("0%3o\t%s/\n", status->st_mode&0777, name);
     }
     return 0;
 }

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     if(argc == 1)
     {
         ftw(".", list, 1);
     }
     else
     {
         ftw(argv[1], list, 1);
     }

     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers of getting all file names recursively with C++11 for Windows and Linux(with `experimental/filesystem`):
For Windows:

```cpp
#include <io.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <windows.h>
void getFiles_w(string path, vector<string>& files) {
    intptr_t hFile = 0; 
    struct _finddata_t fileinfo;  
    string p; 
    if ((hFile = _findfirst(p.assign(path).append("\\*").c_str(), &fileinfo)) != -1) {
        do {
            if ((fileinfo.attrib & _A_SUBDIR)) {
                if (strcmp(fileinfo.name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(fileinfo.name, "..") != 0)
                    getFiles(p.assign(path).append("/").append(fileinfo.name), files);
            }
            else {
                files.push_back(p.assign(path).append("/").append(fileinfo.name));
            }
        } while (_findnext(hFile, &fileinfo) == 0);
    }
}
```

For Linux:

```cpp
#include <experimental/filesystem>
bool getFiles(std::experimental::filesystem::path path, vector<string>& filenames) {
    namespace stdfs = std::experimental::filesystem;
    // http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/directory_iterator
    const stdfs::directory_iterator end{} ;
    
    for (stdfs::directory_iterator iter{path}; iter != end ; ++iter) {
        // http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/is_regular_file 
        if (!stdfs::is_regular_file(*iter)) { // comment out if all names (names of directories tc.) are required 
            if (getFiles(iter->path(), filenames)) 
                return true;
        }
        else {
            filenames.push_back(iter->path().string()) ;
            cout << iter->path().string() << endl;  
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Just remember to link `-lstdc++fs` when you compile it with `g++` in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Employee Visual C++ and WIN API:

```
bool Parser::queryDIR(string dir_name) {
    vector<string> sameLayerFiles;
    bool ret = false;
    string dir = "";
    //employee wide char
    dir = dir_name  + "\\*.*";;
    //employee WIN File API
    WIN32_FIND_DATA  fd;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA  fd_dir;
    HANDLE hFind = ::FindFirstFile(getWC(dir.c_str()), &fd);
    HANDLE hFind_dir = ::FindFirstFile(getWC(dir.c_str()), &fd_dir);
    string str_subdir;
    string str_tmp;
    //recursive call for diving into sub-directories
    do {
        if ((fd_dir.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) ) {
            //ignore trival file node
            while(true) {
                FindNextFile(hFind_dir, &fd_dir);
                str_tmp = wc2str(fd_dir.cFileName);
                if (str_tmp.compare(".") && str_tmp.compare("..")){
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ((fd_dir.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) ) {
                str_subdir = wc2str(fd_dir.cFileName);
                ret = queryDIR(dir_name + "\\" + str_subdir);
            }
        }
    } while(::FindNextFile(hFind_dir, &fd_dir));

    //iterate same layer files
    do { 
        if (!(fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {
            str_tmp = wc2str(fd.cFileName);
            string fname = dir_name + "\\" + str_tmp;
            sameLayerFiles.push_back(fname);
        }
    } while(::FindNextFile(hFind, &fd));    

    for (std::vector<string>::iterator it=sameLayerFiles.begin(); it!=sameLayerFiles.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << "iterated file:" << *it << "..." << std::endl;
        //Doing something with every file here
    }
    return true;   
}
```

Hope my code can help :)

And you can see more details and program screen-shots on [My GitHub](https://github.com/MouChiaHung/Grep)