# Cross platform recursive file list using C++?

Tags: c++, file, cross-platform, execute, v8

What is the most efficient way to recursively list files in a specific directory and its subdirectories? Should I use the standard library, or use some third party?

I want this because I use v8 as a JavaScript engine, and I want to execute all scripts in some directory (and its subdirectories). If there's any built-in way to do that in v8, great :)

It should support Windows, Linux and OS X.

Thanks.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273/how-do-you-iterate-through-every-file-directory-recursively-in-standard-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a generic cross-platform C++ solution, check out [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)

Comment: How can I do that with boost::filesystem?

Comment: @Excl, you can start by reading about it at the link Cogwheel gave you

Comment: @Excl: the simple_ls example in particular would be worth a look

Comment: They need to update their tutorials to include `recursive_directory_iterator`.

Comment: does anyone know of a header-only solution?