# C++ how to check if folder is empty / list existing files

Tags: c++, list, file, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you iterate through every file/directory recursively in standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273/how-do-you-iterate-through-every-file-directory-recursively-in-standard-c)

Hello everyone!

I've been looking for a way to check if a determined folder is empty or not, and if it isn't, list the existing files in the folder, but of course to no avail.

I've been looking around and found something called dirent.h and something else called boost. Is there any way to achieve my goal without using this? If there isn't which one would be the best bet?

thanx in advance

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170440/cross-platform-recursive-file-list-using-c and probably others.

Comment: The upshot of any of the related questions is that no, there is no way to do this without using some sort of library like boost. The functionality isn't part of the C++ standard.