# Failing to Parse System Directories using QFileSystemModel for different Audio/Video Files

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qfilesystemmodel

I am newbie in Qt and have started working on it from past few days. I have come across a situation where I need to parse/traverse my System Directories and search for files like .mp3, .mpg etc.

Well in my .ui I have 2 Tree Views, one towards right and other towards left. The left one displays System Directories and on selecting the drive, the right treeview displays the .mp3, .mpg etc files.

Here is my Cpp class:

```
    //Gets called on App startup
void PanasonicViewer::onCamStartup()
{
    m_SystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    m_SystemListViewModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    m_SystemModel->setRootPath(QDir::homePath());
    ui->DriveView->setModel(m_SystemModel); //Left side TreeView
    ui->DriveListView->setModel(m_SystemListViewModel); //Right Side TreeView

    // regard less how many columns you can do this using for:
    for(int nCount = 1; nCount < m_SystemModel->columnCount(); nCount++)
       ui->DriveView->hideColumn(nCount);
}

void PanasonicViewer::on_DriveView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QStringList sDriveFilters;

    QString sPath = m_SystemModel->fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath();
    ui->DriveListView->setRootIndex(m_SystemListViewModel->setRootPath(sPath));    

    m_SystemModel->setRootPath(QDir::homePath());
    m_SystemModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs );
    m_SystemListViewModel->setFilter( QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot );

    sDriveFilters << "*.aac" << "*.wmv" << "*.avi" << "*.mpeg" << "*.mov" << "*.3gp" << "*.flv" << "*.mp3" ;

    m_SystemListViewModel->setNameFilters(sDriveFilters);
    m_SystemListViewModel->setNameFilterDisables(false);
}

Here is my .h file:

  QFileSystemModel *m_SystemModel;
  QFileSystemModel *m_SystemListViewModel;
```

When I run my app, it displays only those audio/video files which are present in the Drive. I mean it doesn’t parse the folders present inside the drive where audio/video files are present. It just displays the files which are in the drive and not subdirectories. How can i achieve it? :)

Comment: Set root path should be set to the current directory you are setting it to the HomeDir every time...

Comment: @opc0de:I tried currentPath too but it doesn't seem to display files in subfolders

Answer (score 1):

"Computer do what you said, but not you want"

If you want get all files present inside the drive -- you must recursively go thru all your directories.

Here is similar and answered question: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273/how-do-you-iterate-through-every-file-directory-recursively-in-standard-c).

By one of answers, in Qt you can use this approach:

```
#include <qapplication.h>
#include <qdir.h>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    QApplication a( argc, argv );
    QDir currentDir = QDir::current();

    currentDir.setFilter( QDir::Dirs );
    QStringList entries = currentDir.entryList();
    for( QStringList::ConstIterator entry=entries.begin(); entry!=entries.end(); ++entry) 
    {
          std::cout << *entry << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ideally this should not be present in `main()`. It needs to be written in cpp where I am dealing with files. Basically I am concerned about .mp3 and .mpg files only. I tried following the same chunk but it throws error as `'cout' is not a member of 'std'`. Would be helpful if you could guide me :)

Comment: Of course, you are right -- you must adopt this code to your purposes. Whats about error you got -- you need to include `<iostream>` to source file.

Comment: Tried the <iostream> but didnt work. It throws the following error: `no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << entry.QList<T>::const_iterator::operator* [with T = QString]()'`.... Strange..... But it looks like this code might give me all the files inside the drive. Ideally I need only audio and video files.

Comment: `std::cout` is just for output your entries, if in doesn't work -- don't use it now. Try to include `QDebug` and use `qDebug()<<*entry` instead.

Comment: Well this works fine...... But my concern is to traverse only for Audio/Video files and display them in my treeview (right side). I have set the filter accordingly in my above code. Have a look and see if I am missing something.