# os.walk analogue in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtcore, qfile

Before I can continue to implement recursive dir/file search with some filtering for some tasks I want to know if Qt/PyQt has analogue of `os.walk`.

Main app is a GUI app in PyQt4 and all text fields in a `QString`s and path objects (files, directories) uses `QFile`, `QDir`, `QFileinfo` for manipulations.

As analogue I mean fast and convenient recursive fs-tree traversal tool.

Should I use `os.walk` or something much faster and more informative?

PS. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1471012/601684) can help me but I'm not sure if this more efficient than `os.walk`.

Comment: You could also give [scandir](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir) a try.

Comment: @JanneKarila: I'm afraid that another one dependency isn't good for that task. But thank you anyway. Added to bookmarks till the good times come )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I use os.walk or something much faster and more informative?

There is none, and I would recommend using `os.walk` in python if you can. It is just as good as it gets.

It is not only because Qt does not have such a convenience method, but even if you write your own mechanism based on `QDir`, you will have access to all the three variables without hand-crafting like with `os.walk`.

If you are desperate about using Qt, then you could have the following traverse function below I used myself a while ago.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QDir>
#include <QFileInfoList>
#include <QDebug>

void traverse( const QString& dirname )
{
    QDir dir(dirname);
    dir.setFilter(QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks | QDir::NoDot | QDir::NoDotDot);

    foreach (QFileInfo fileInfo, dir.entryInfoList()) {
      if (fileInfo.isDir() && fileInfo.isReadable())
          traverse(fileInfo.absoluteFilePath());
      else
          qDebug() << fileInfo.absoluteFilePath();
    }
}

int main()
{
    traverse("/usr/lib");
    return 0;
}
```

or simply the following forfor large directories and in general since it scales better and more convenient:

```
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QDirIterator it("/etc", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while (it.hasNext())
        qDebug() << it.next();
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = qdir-traverse
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./qdir-traverse
```

Then, you will get all the traversed files printed. You can start customizing it then further to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for clear and detailed answer. Now the tool is selected and all doubts are gone.

Comment: Hmm... So what about http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfilesystemmodel.html?

Comment: This can be done much more efficiently with [QDirIterator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdiriterator.html). Don't know whether it would out-perform `os.walk`, though.

Comment: @ekhumoro: absolutely, and I was actually writing that. The former code is from pre-qdiriterator times.

Comment: @Laszlo: Now I'm confused :( But I will compare both of methods for speed and usecases. Thank you anyway! :) Your help gave great task to my brain to work with!

Comment: @Крайст: why so? I would use os.walk, but I provided the alternatives if you really want to use Qt. I mean, people usually use os.walk along with the three variables. If you do not need that from os.walk, just listing the directories, the qt solutions work, otherwise you need to hand-craft the three variables, so it depends on your use case, but I had the assumption that you would need the three variables, too. There is nothing like QDir::traverse or QDir::walk in that sense. :) I would not worry much about performance because if you did, you would not use python. ;-)

Comment: @LaszloPapp: "I would not worry much about performance because if you did, you would not use python. ;-)" — great, great, great!! Great quote at all times! :) PS. Think that topic can be closed.