# Go through all files in a directory

Tags: c++, windows, directory

I'm having some trouble with directories & c++. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on a Windows setup.

> Directory : .../Files which contains some text files (f1.txt , f2.txt , f3.txt)

I need the function to go through all the files in that directory one by one.

```
A file is open - cout the filename
//Do some stuff 
close - then move to next file
```

I have the code to read a single file. But I have no idea how to go through all of them & display the names.

```
void goThroughDirectory()
{
    while("there are remaining files , do something , then go to next one")
    {

        cout << "The Name of the File Currently being processed" << endl;

        // While inside a file
        ifstream FileX("FileName.txt");

        int lineNum = 0;
        string s;

        while (!FileX.eof())
        {
            getline(FileX, s);

            if (s.size() != 0)
            {
                lineNum++;
                cout << s << endl;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

the expected output should be :

```
// file name
f1  

// contents
a
b
c

// file name
f2 

// contents
a
b
c

.......
```

Comment: You will need to use `Boost` or an OS API.  There are no standard provisions in C++ for iterating through a directory.

Comment: BTW, please edit your question with your platform information, such as operating system.

Comment: see [612097](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273/how-do-you-iterate-through-every-file-directory-recursively-in-standard-c

Comment: Ask your vendor to implement the Filesystem TS :-)