# Reading all files in computer

Tags: c++

I want to write a little program which lists all the files in the computer and then outputs their paths.

For example:

```
Jhon.txt => D:/Smth/Smth/Jhon.txt
Mom.txt => D:/Smth/Mom.txt
Dad.exe => C:/Dad.exe
```

And so on.

So I want to ask what would be best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: read the source for GNU coreutils program ``ls``

Comment: Or rather GNU `find` (from the findutils).

Comment: Use a portable framework.  Otherwise, since file directories are platform specific, tell us which platform you are using.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273/how-do-you-iterate-through-every-file-directory-recursively-in-standard-c

Comment: See if you can find the code for locate and updatedb.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu 12.04, I used the "#include dirent.h" interface to access functions (like opendir(), closedir(), readdir() etc.)  and constants for this effort.

With these, my program can read dirs and pfns starting at a directory. (But you don't want to start at dir "/", and there are several dir's you should skip.)

At a terminal, try man opendir.

I have only used this on Linux (specifically ubuntu 12.04 and a few earlier versions of ubuntu.)

"dirent.h"  does fairly well on NTFS, but NTFS has some interesting kludges I no longer wish to work on.

Good luck.