# Reading files in a folder xcode c++

Tags: c++, xcode, file, directory

I am fairly new to C++. I have been trying to access the names of files in a specific folder. I'm not sure if I should use a vector or a list.  I tried a list, just because that's what I'm used to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

list<string> file_list(string file)
{
    list<string> list;
    ifstream files;
    string line;
    files.open(file);
    while (getline(files, line)) {
        list.push_back(line);
    }
    files.close();
    cout << &list << endl;
    return list;
}
```

When I debug the variable `line` stays blank and it prints off `0x7fff5fbff6b0`.
I am trying access my downloads folder. The string variable 'file'  is a direct path to it. It opens just fine, but I can't access the file names inside it.

Answer (score 0):

C++ standard library doesn't have a filesystem access library ([yet](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/directory_iterator)). If you want to enumerate all the files in a folder and your compiler doesn't have the `std::experimental::filesystem`, you can use [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

This

```
cout << &list << endl;
```

prints out the address of list, that mysterious `0x7fff5fbff6b0`, not the contents of list.

To print the contents you need something more like

```
for (string & str: list)
{
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

Oh, and lose the ; at the end of

```
list<string> file_list(string file);
```

And Duhr. Yeah. Totally missed the point of what OP was trying to do.

Reading a directory like a file doesn't work with a stream. You will have to use a platform-specific method. Give this question a read: [How do you iterate through every file/directory recursively in standard C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273/how-do-you-iterate-through-every-file-directory-recursively-in-standard-c)