# How to read in multiple text files into a program?

Tags: c++

I am writing a function that will take in a text file and do some manipulation on it. The files are stored in somewhat different places, such as:
/Documents/news/sports/something.txt where sports will be a folder with 20+ txt files

There are 20 more categories, stored such as: /Documents/news/next_category/something_else.txt

So the problem is that I want to pass in every txt file inside each folder inside the news folder, into my program, one by one. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you want to recursively enumerate the contents of a directory. I would use boost filesystem. It even has a recursive dir walk sample http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

also look here for other solutions [How do you iterate through every file/directory recursively in standard C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273/how-do-you-iterate-through-every-file-directory-recursively-in-standard-c)

Answer (score 0):

Not with pure C++.  C++ has no concept of directories, so you'll either have to interface with your OS's directory functions (like the C POSIX opendir and family) or use some library (like [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm))

Comment: its interesting that c++ has no concept of directories but it does understand threads - an arguably more complex concept

Comment: I agree that it is weird, but threads were a more recent addition themselves.  I think c++ filesystem stuff is supposed to be likely in c++17.

Comment: @pm100 Generalizing directories across all possible operating systems is not as trivial as you might think.

Comment: @Barmar Neither is generalizing threads.