# Recursive folder read C++

Tags: c++, recursion, boost, directory

I have about 6000 .txt files to read. 
There are many folders, each containing many sub-folders, which again contain many sub-folders and at the end of every sub-folder there is a text file.
the text file contains few numbers which I have to read.
My issue is recursively going through the folders and sub-folders.

I am able to do this in Python, but not in C++.

Can someone help me with C++ (preferably without Boost)

Comment: Hints: 1) Keep the path as a `std::string`. 2) Use `std::stack<std::string>` to help traverse the file system.

Comment: BTW, if you are not using Boost, you will need platform specific API to access the filesystem.

Comment: Boost, platform API, or C libraries are the ways to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you iterate through every file/directory recursively in standard C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273/how-do-you-iterate-through-every-file-directory-recursively-in-standard-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, best available thing is [boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-recursive_directory_iterator) or, in case of fresh compiler - [std::experimental::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/recursive_directory_iterator)

Examples are available in links provided

Answer (score 0):

I assume, from your mention of Boost, that you are aware of boost::filesystem, but are looking for an alternative.  I'm not aware of any that are portable.  A portable file system library is planned for the C++17 Standard Library, but it is based on boost::filesystem.  On POSIX-compliant OSes, you could perhaps use the API functions declared in the dirent.h POSIX (straight C) header.

Comment: You are right, I do know of boost::filesystem. I just wanted a C++ alternative before I gave in to Boost. Thanks!

Comment: In VC++ you can use CFileFind for recursive file search