# Hash file recursive and save into vector Cryptopp

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++

I want to get the hash files. in current path has 4 files. and it need to hash and save into vector output to perform other task later.

```
CryptoPP::SHA256 hash;
std::vector<std::string> output;
for(auto& p : std::experimental::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(std::experimental::filesystem::current_path()))
{
    if (std::experimental::filesystem::is_regular_file(status(p)))
    {
        CryptoPP::FileSource(p, true, new CryptoPP::HashFilter(hash, new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(output))), true);
    }
}

for (auto& list : output)
{
    std::cout << list << std::endl;
}
getchar();
return 0;
```

i get this errors

1. Description
   no instance of constructor "CryptoPP::FileSource::FileSource" matches the argument list
2. Description
   no instance of constructor "CryptoPP::StringSinkTemplate::StringSinkTemplate [with T=std::string]" matches the argument list
3. Description
   'CryptoPP::StringSinkTemplate::StringSinkTemplate(const CryptoPP::StringSinkTemplate &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector>' to 'T &'
4. Description
   '': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'CryptoPP::FileSource'

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduce your code to its essentials:

```
std::vector<std::string> output;
FileSource(p, true, new HashFilter(hash, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(output))), true);
```

The Crypto++ `StringSink` accepts a reference to a `std::string`, not a `std::vector<std::string>`. Also see [`StringSink`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_string_sink.html) in the Crypto++ manual.

The `FileSource` needs a filename, not a directory name. Given `p` is a directory iterator and not a file iterator I'm guessing you are going to have additional troubles once you get the name as a C-string or `std::string`.

You should use something like:

```
std::vector<std::string> output;
std::string str;
std::string fname = p...;

FileSource(fname.c_str(), true, new HashFilter(hash, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(str))), true);

output.push_back(str);
```

I have no idea how to get the filename from `p`, which is a `std::experimental::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator`. That's why the code just says `std::string fname = p...;`.

You should ask another question about `filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator`. Also see [How do you iterate through every file/directory recursively in standard C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32889434/608639)