# C++ iterate through a path recursively. Error: no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::filesystem::directory_entry'

Tags: c++, for-loop, recursion, c++17

I want to create a loop that iterates through all folders and files in a path iteratively. I have the following code (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273/how-do-you-iterate-through-every-file-directory-recursively-in-standard-c))

```
#include <filesystem> 
#include <iostream>

for (const auto& dirEntry : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator("some path here")) {
        std::cout << dirEntry;
    }
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
'<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::filesystem::directory_entry' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Can anybody explain how I can fix this? I am using C++17

Comment: You need to define how you want directory iterators to be printed. Easiest to just convert to string, if that's what you need.

Comment: Try: `std::cout << dirEntry.path();`

Comment: My implementation (gcc version 10.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)) has a defined `operator<<` and your code works, copy-pasted, but when you dive into the implementation you can see a comment just above the definiton of the `<<`, which says: `// _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS // 3171. LWG 2989 breaks directory_entry stream insertion`. Additionally, I did not find anything in the standard which would even hint that there is an `operator<<` defined for `directory_entry`. In that case you'd need to use `.path()` or workarounds like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. `std::cout << dirEntry.path();` indeed works. However, I am now wondering why I cannot convert `dirEntry.path().filename()` to a string like `std::string file = dirEntry.path().filename()`. Shouldn't `dirEntry.path().filename()` be of type string?. The error is 'initializing': cannot convert from `'std::filesystem::path' to 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'`

Comment: @masteryoda436 To convert filename to string use the `string()` method of `std::filesystem::path`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path

Answer (score 0):

there is no overload in the standard library for `operator<<` which takes a right hand operator of type `std::filesystem::directory_entry` but there is exist one for `std::filesystem::path` which you can obtain from `std::filesystem::directory_entry` using `path()` method, so all should you do is to convert this line :

`std::cout << dirEntry;`

to :

`std::cout << dirEntry.path();`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This indeed works. However, I am now wondering why I cannot convert `dirEntry.path().filename()` to a string like `std::string file = dirEntry.path().filename()`. Shouldn't `dirEntry.path().filename()` be of type string?. The error is `'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::filesystem::path' to 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'`

Comment: @masteryoda436 You'll have better luck if you stop guessing, and consult your favourite documentation instead to find out how to use these functions.

Comment: You are right, sorry. For people who are interested: `dirEntry.path().filename().string()` worked for me.