# I cannot read files from Turkish character directory in C

Tags: c, file-io, directory, character-encoding

In C Programming; I cannot read files from a directory with Turkish characters, but if I change the name of the folder containing Turkish characters, I can read them.

1. Os Name: Windows 10
2. Programming Language: C
3. IDE: Visual Studio Code

I have folder named **Ülke**.
I cannot read files from this directory.

```
DIR *dr = opendir("C:/Users/softeng/tutorials/comp/Ülke/");
```

but When I rename this folder to **Ulke**, I can read it.

```
DIR *dr = opendir("C:/Users/softeng/tutorials/comp/Ulke/");
```

All Code;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <locale.h>
  
int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
    struct dirent *de;
    DIR *dr = opendir("C:/Users/softeng/tutorials/comp/Ülke/");
  
    if (dr == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open current directory" );
        return 0;
    }
  
    while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL)
        printf("%s\n", de->d_name);

    closedir(dr);    
    return 0;
}
```

How can i solve it.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Also, did you define the function `opendir` yourself or is that part of some API you are using?

Comment: i use mingw64-gcc-g++, I have fully attached the Code I wrote. Can you check the Post again?

Comment: If you're using mingw64-gcc-g++, you can use C++ classes like `std::filesystem`. That understands wide characters like `L"C:/Users/softeng/tutorials/comp/Ülke/"`. Notice the leading L

Comment: @MSalters How can I do it in C?

Comment: Probably have to use Win32 functions instead of emulated posix ones

Comment: Looks like it's `FindFirstFileW()` and friends. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/listing-the-files-in-a-directory

Comment: @ResulZoroğlu: If there wa a C answer, I'd write it, but I commented to make sure you indeed need C instead of C++. It's a bit weird that you're using a C++ compiler for C.

Comment: @MSalters There is no other reason why I chose to write a simple program. What do you recommend?

Comment: @ResulZoroğlu: If you know C++, obviously C++. [Example simple function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32889434/15416). Just use `auto myPath=L"C:/Users/softeng/tutorials/comp/Ülke/";`

Comment: @MSalters thank you for answer but i dont know C++, I only need to do directory read operations. but this is how i had the problem. I am researching how I can solve this situation in C.

Comment: *opendir* deals with ascii character strings (char *), whether `Ü` is an extended character set. You probably need to convert it to utf8/unicode format. There are 'c'-based functions around which do conversions, e.g., https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html#:~:text=The%20most%20interesting%20one%20for,that%20refers%20to%20a%20character. You can try those or, as suggested earlier, use embedded c++ support for conversions. It might also be possible to set your code editor to treat all chars as unicode/utf8 chars, It might also resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vs Code >Preferences>Settings

Then;

Search

Files Encoding:

You can choose ISO-8859-9

And setlocale(LC_ALL="Turkish")

Answer (score 0):

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8")
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "turkish")
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "iso-8859-9")

you can try these code.

Comment: I tried but didn't work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).